# Custom Action to Print multiple list items

Tags: 2013, list-view, ribbon, custom-action, printing

A client has requested to print every selected list item (and its attachments) with one button click. How can this be achieved? Can I add a custom action in the ribbon that detects every list item selected and then prints it's display form?

Comment: What do they mean? Print each item's details as separate pages or print a tabular view of the selected items? Are the items generic list items or documents in a library?

Comment: Sorry for bumping an old thread, but the solution in this thread seems to be exactly what I need. Can someone please explain to me how I run the javascript from a custom action? I'm new to Sharepoint but have been goofing around with web development for a while.

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved to a certain extent if you, for example, create a list view with appropriately formatted list items and a SharePoint Designer custom action with a javascript like

```
javascript:{
(function() {
var myctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(), 
    selected = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(myctx), 
    list = []; 

for (var item in selected) {
    list.push(selected[item].id);
}; 

if (list.length > 32) {alert("Please select only as many as 32 items at once.");}
else {
    var url = location.origin + "/YOURSITECOLLECTION/Lists/YOURLIST/YOURPRINTVIEW.aspx"
              + "?FilterName=ID&FilterMultiValue="
              + list.join(';'); 

    location.href = url; 
}

})();

}
```

The target list view may also reference a trivial masterpage to remove unneeded chrome and contain a javascript to invoke the browser's native print dialog.

Comment: Can this script be used for SP2010 also?

Comment: Yes, it works with sp2010

Comment: I added this script in "Navigate to URL" section of "View Ribbon" Custom Actions but it doesn't print the select items,rather it filters the selected items and display them in the view.

Comment: Repeat: The target list view may also reference a trivial masterpage to remove unneeded chrome and contain a javascript to invoke the browser's native print dialog.